# Use of class template node requires template arguments C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have two classes defined in C++ seen below.

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>

template <class T> class node   {
public:
    int NodeID;  //ID used to identify node when inserting/deleting/finding.
    T data;  //generic data encapsulated in each node.
    std::vector<node*> children;  //child nodes, list of ptrs
    std::vector<node*> parents;  //parent nodes list of ptrs
};


class DAG {//Class for the graph

    std::vector<node*> Nodes;

}
```

However I am getting an error within DAG saying "Use of class template node requires template arguments". I am completely lost any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `node` is template class. `node<SomeType>` is a type. If you write `node*` what would be the type `T` in `node` class?

Comment: To put it in other words: `node` is not a class. It serves as a template for multiple classes, which you get from `node<T>` with `T` being some other type. Also note that they don't share a common baseclass, just in case you wanted to use them like that. Hint: You probably want a `template<class T> class DAG`, which contains a `vector<node<T>*>` as member.

Comment: What is possibly confusing is that *inside* the `node` class you can use just `node*`. That's because at this point the name `node` refers to the class itself, and its `T` parameter is assumed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Solution 1

You can **solve** this by specifying a type in `std::vector<node*> Nodes;`  as shown below:

```
std::vector<node<int>*> Nodes; //note i have added int you can add any type
```

##### Solution 2

Another solution would be to make class `DAG` a **class template** as shown below:

```
template<typename T>
class DAG {//Class for the graph

    std::vector<node<T>*> Nodes;

};
```

Comment: Thanks Anoop, however am I correct in understanding that this means each individual DAG object would only contain nodes of a single type?

Comment: @BenBorg You're welcome. In my second solution, `DAG` becomes a class template. This means for example, each `DAG<T>` object will have a data member named `Nodes` which will be a `std::vector` of `node<T>*` objects. So lets say we have `T=int`, this will mean that each `DAG<int>` object will have a member named `Nodes` that will be a `std::vector` of elements of type *pointer to `node<int>`* (that is `node<int>*`).

Comment: Yes so for example DAG<int> would have nodes<int>, but I  want DAG to have nodes which can be of any type.

Comment: That is not possible with templates. You can use `std::any`, which provides _type erasing_.
Another solution would be to make a class hierarchy

Comment: @BenBorg You should/can use `std::any` for this purpose. But i think my current answer solves your original question. You should ask a separate question for your modified requirement.

Comment: @BenBorg If you ask a separate question, then in your separate question you can mention other additional details like what exactly you want to achieve. There we will answer accordingly otherwise my current answer will become obsolete. Generally we should ask [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) on SO.

Comment: Hi sry Anoop Im very new to Stackoverflow wasn't sure how to mark answers as correct before now.

Comment: @Ben Ok no problem. :)